# When client closes server crashes

Tags: c++, server, winsock

I am creating a multi threaded server which will allow for multiple clients to join. But I have recently added this code to my client:

```
if (CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT == true)
{
    send(ConnectSocket, (char*)quit, 1, 0);

    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_BOTH);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
```

This should send a quit message whenever the console is closed, but whenever I close the console it throws a runtime library error and makes me abort. It comes up with `recv()` function failed and `send()` function failed, which means the socket hasn't shut down correctly.

Here is my server code:

```
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "game.h"
#include <fstream>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"
#define DEFAULT_IP "127.0.0.1 "

std::mutex MyMutex;
int ClientCount;

using namespace std;

std::ofstream outfile ("serverconfig.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);

int callThread(SOCKET ClientSocket,int nCount)
{
    MyMutex.lock();
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    int iResult, iSendResult;

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    printf("thread count: %d\n", nCount);

    do {
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult == 1)
        {
            cout << "Client " << nCount << " has left" << endl;
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            nCount--;
        }

        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

            // Echo the buffer back to the sender

            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }

            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
        {
            nCount--;
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        MyMutex.unlock();
    }
    while (iResult > 0);
}

int __cdecl main(void)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    int iSendResult;
    ClientCount = 0;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    std::thread myThreads[100];
    game game1;
    string type;
    string map;
    int level;
    int max;
    int min;

    //output server details to file 
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("serverconfig.txt");
    outfile << DEFAULT_IP;
    outfile << DEFAULT_PORT;
    outfile.close();

    //get start up data
    /*cout << "please choose a type: 1: Deathmatch 2: Capture the flag 3: Blood Diamond" << endl;
    cin >> type;
    cout << "Please choose a map:" << endl;
    cin >> map;
    cout << "please choose a difficulty level between 1 - 3: " << endl;
    cin >> level;
    cout << "Please choose the max number of clients: " << endl;
    cin >> max;
    cout << "Please choose the min number of clients" << endl; 
    cin >> min; */

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = ::bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);
    if (listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    for (;;)
    {
        //creating a temp socket for accepting a connction
        SOCKET ClientSocket;
        // Accept a client socket
        ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
        if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            myThreads[ClientCount] = std::thread(callThread, ClientSocket, ClientCount);
            ClientCount++;
            printf("normal count: %d\n", ClientCount);
            if (ClientCount == 1)
            {
                cout << "Waiting for another Client to connect" << endl;
            }
            /*if (ClientCount >= 2)
            {
                cout << "Game" << type << "in progress" << endl;
            }*/

        }
    }

    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my client code:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

using namespace std;

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
        *ptr = NULL,
        hints;
    char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    int quit = 1;
    // Send and Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        if (CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT == true)
        {
            send(ConnectSocket, (char*)quit, 1, 0);

            iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_BOTH);
            if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ConnectSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    while (iResult > 0);

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, you'll have to provide the code since without it it's impossible to say what you have done.

Comment: I have provided both bits of code for you

Comment: `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` is a compile time constant defined as `2`, so `if (CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT == true)` will never evaluate as true and thus everything inside the `if` block will never execute. You would need to use something more like `if (dwCtrlType == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT)` instead. Also, you say `send()` and `recv()` are failing, but you didn't say how they are failing. What are the error codes they report? Is the failure on the server side or the client side? And you say your server is multithreaded, but where is the code that is stopping the threads or closing the listening socket?

Comment: Okay thanks, CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT == 2 will work?

Comment: @ElliottBailey: no, use `if (dwCtrlType == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT)` instead, like I said earlier, where `dwCtrlType` is the input parameter of your registered `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()` callback function.

Comment: @ElliottBailey: looks like you are not even using `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()`, which means you can't use `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` at all. But more importantly, there are a LOT of errors in your server code. It is misusing a mutex, calling `WSACleanup()` in the client threads, calling `closesocket(ClientSocket)` twice on `recv()` failure, not waiting for client threads to end while shutting down the server, and not closing the listening socket during shutdown.

Comment: @ElliottBailey: on the client side, `send(ConnectSocket, (char*)quit, 1, 0);` is wrong, it should be `send(ConnectSocket, (char*)&quit, sizeof(quit), 0);` instead. `quit` is an integer initialized to a value of `1`, which you are then type-casting to a `char*` pointer. Memory address 0x00000001 is not a valid address to read from. You need to read from the address where `quit` resides, thus `&quit`. If you only want to sent 1 byte instead of 4, `quit` should be declared as an `(unsigned) char` instead of an `int`.

Comment: I am very new to this, and have limited resourcres to learn from. But thanks for telling me my errors. I am getting the mutex error aswell now. I don't know how to set up ctrlHandler any links to a tutorial or an explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: @ElliottBailey: start with the documentation: [SetConsoleCtrlHandler function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016.aspx) and [Registering a Control Handler Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685049.aspx).